# Ejbql query with in in where clause

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, ejb, querying, ejbql

I try to do this query :

```
SELECT x FROM CompteUtilisateur x, Mail m WHERE m.adresse = :param_mail AND m IN (x.listeMail)
```

I fails, query generated for the WHERE clause is :

```
where
compteutil0_.id=listemail2_.fk__compte__id 
and listemail2_.fk__mail__id=mailimpl3_.id 
and mailimpl1_.adresse=? 
and (
    mailimpl1_.id in (
        .
    )
)
```

What am I missing ? Is it possible to do what I whant to do ?
Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN using with sub query, try MEMBER OF.

```
SELECT x FROM CompteUtilisateur x, Mail m WHERE m.adresse = :param_mail AND m MEMBER OF x.listeMail
```